# iphone: i want to use integrate via yelp for Getting yelp Data how can achive that?

Tags: iphone

I want to use Yelp Data Integration in i phone application please give me some URL for use this

i am now use this Website [Yelp Developer Website](http://www.yelp.com/developers/)

Answer (score 1):

You use the following link of yelp api to retrieve the restaurant data.
[this](http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=yelp&tl_lat=37.9&tl_long=-122.5&br_lat=37.788022&br_long=-122.399797&limit=3&ywsid=%5BInsert%20your%20API%20Key%5D)

http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=yelp&tl_lat=37.9&tl_long=-122.5&br_lat=37.788022&br_long=-122.399797&limit=3&ywsid=[Insert your API key]

Comment: Please Add URL in this link as a text